# Third cordinates of triangle in $\mathbb R^3$ in specific plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

In three dimensional space, there is a plane whose normal is vector **n**,

In that plane three points exist as **C,P and T**, to form triangle

Distances between them are known as:

|CP|=r

|CT|=k

|PT|=l

It is right triangle as angle at P is 90:  angle( CPT) is 90 degree

Coordinates of C and T are known.

Normal Vector to plane is known: that is **n**

***I*** need to find coordinates of P (that exist in same plane)?

Comment: This is not *our* work, but *your work*,  To refer to WE, you must participate, and I see no contributions from you in your question.

Comment: Find the coordinates of $H$, the projection of $P$ on $TC$. Then $P-H$ is proportional to $\mathbf{n}\times(H-T)$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from Thales's theorem, that $\mathbf{P}$ lies on the circle whose center is the midpoint of $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{T}$.  Thus define the vector

$\mathbf{v_1} = 0.5(\mathbf{C} - \mathbf{T}) $

and

$\mathbf{v_2} = \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{v_1} $

where $n$ is assumed to be a unit vector (if it is not, then we have to normalise it by dividing it by its length).

Point $\mathbf{P}$ is given by

$\mathbf{P} = 0.5(\mathbf{C} + \mathbf{T}) +  \mathbf{v_1} \cos t +  \mathbf{v_2} \sin t , \hspace{20pt} t \in [0, 2\pi) $

There can be two values of $\theta$ whose values are:

$\theta = \phi $, and $ \theta =  2\pi - \phi $

where $\phi = 2 \tan^{-1} \dfrac{ | \mathbf{PC} |}{| \mathbf{PT}| } $